# Is a WMS of vectors a stream of images or of data attributes?

Tags: wms

I used to read that `WMS` is a stream of images, for example : `image/png`.
And that, if you need additional data about what is underlying, you have to send `WFS` requests aside.

But what about `WMS` streams of vectors (instead of rasters). I used to open a `WMS` layer with `QGIS`, and at that time I don't provide a `WFS` layer with it. `QGIS` is able to show me attributes content of what I am clicking on with my mouse.

What does the `WMS` stream carries to the client then ? Images ? It has to transfer data attributes too, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking a WMS gives singular images (or videos) on request (GetMap), so output formats will be normally, image/png, image/jpeg, image/tiff.  A caveat would be use of WMS to serve MapBox vector tiles.

A WMS is not a streaming service.

The data the WMS converts into its output can be vector or raster, or some combination of those.  The attribute data of the input data are not available in the GetMap response, but may be available as part of a separate request, a GetFeatureInfo request.

As WMS requests are stateless, the GetFeatureInfo request must pass the majority of the request parameters to request the map image that was clicked on, plus the coordinates of the pixel (point) that was clicked on, plus the output format for the attribute information to be returned in.

So a WMS GetMap request generated by QGIS might look like:

> http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/wms?language=eng&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=50.179445759563,-4.41340973640857,50.9615344710795,-3.2834397199341&WIDTH=877&HEIGHT=607&LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=XML&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFEFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&

and give a map image like:

[image: WMS GetMap request result image]

and the GetFeatureInfo request would be like:

> http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/wms?language=eng&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=50.179445759563,-4.41340973640857,50.9615344710795,-3.2834397199341&WIDTH=877&HEIGHT=607&LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=XML&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFEFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=194&J=162&

That is we have replaced **REQUEST=GetMap&** with **REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&**  and added **QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL&** the layer of the map we want to query on, **INFO_FORMAT=text/html&** the format we want the response in, and **I=194&** **J=162&** the pixel coordinates of the point clicked on.